# Git rebase: conflicts keep blocking progress

Tags: git, rebase

I have a git branch (called v4), that was made from master just yesterday.  There were a couple of changes to master, that I want to get into v4.  So, in v4, I tried to do a rebase from master, and one file keeps screwing things up: a one-line text file, that contains the version number.  This file is `app/views/common/version.txt`, which before rebasing contains this text:

```
v1.4-alpha-02
```

Here's what I'm doing:

```
> git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: new version, new branch
error: patch failed: app/views/common/version.txt:1
error: app/views/common/version.txt: patch does not apply
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging app/views/common/version.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/views/common/version.txt
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 new version, new branch

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To restore the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

The `version.txt` now looks like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:app/views/common/version.txt
v1.4-alpha-02
=======
v1.4-alpha-01
>>>>>>> new version, new branch:app/views/common/version.txt
```

So, I tidy it up and it looks like this now:

```
v1.4-alpha-02
```

and then I tried to carry on: at first I try a commit:

```
> git commit -a -m "merged"
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

No luck there.  So, I was trying to add the file:

```
git add app/views/common/version.txt
```

No response.  No news is good news, I guess.  So, I try to continue:

```
> git rebase --continue
Applying: new version, new branch
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To restore the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

It's at this point, after going round and round with this, that I'm banging my head off the desk.

What's going on here?  What am I doing wrong?  Can anyone set me straight?

EDIT - for unutbu

I changed the file as you suggested and get the same error:

```
> git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: new version, new branch
error: patch failed: app/views/common/version.txt:1
error: app/views/common/version.txt: patch does not apply
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging app/views/common/version.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/views/common/version.txt
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 new version, new branch

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To restore the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

Comment: thanks for asking this question .. i was facing the exact same problem

Comment: would be nice if you confirm some answer

Comment: @MaxWilliams, I think you (like me) have misinterpreted  [@unutbu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4033058/277826)'s advice: 1) first you run `git rebase master` _and let it fail_; 2) then you edit `version.txt` and make it as it should look at that point, and save the edit; 3) then you `git add .../version.txt`; 4) then you do `git rebase --continue` (_**not** 'commit'_)! If `rebase --continue` succeeds here, _it is already committed_ (no need for `git commit` here!) - so all that is left to do is `git push` (if you use a remote repo). Hope this helps, if I got it right `:)` - cheers!

Comment: @MaxWilliams, did you ever get an answer for this: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/187288 ( I will promptly delete this after a reply if someone else doesn't get there first!!)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem with a rebase. My problem was caused because one of my commit only changed a file, and when resolving, I discarded the change introduced in this commit. I was able to solve my problem by skipping the corresponding commit (`git rebase --skip`).

You can reproduce this problem in a test repository. First create the repository.

```
$ mkdir failing-merge
$ cd failing-merge
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in $HOME/failing-merge/.git/
```

Then commit the original content of `version.txt` in master.

```
$ echo v1.4-alpha-02 > version.txt
$ git add version.txt
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 2eef0a5] initial
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 version.txt
```

Create the `v4` branch and change the content of `version.txt`.

```
$ git checkout -b v4
Switched to a new branch 'v4'
$ echo v1.4-alpha-03 > version.txt
$ git add version.txt
$ git commit -m v4
[v4 1ef8c9b] v4
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

Go back to `master` and change the content of `version.txt` so that there will be a conflit during the rebase.

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ echo v1.4-alpha-04 > version.txt
$ git add version.txt
$ git commit -m master
[master 7313eb3] master
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

Switch back to `v4` branch and try to rebase. It fails with a conflit in `version.txt` as planned.

```
$ git checkout v4
Switched to branch 'v4'
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: v4
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging version.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in version.txt
Recorded preimage for 'version.txt'
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 v4

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To restore the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
$ cat version.txt
<<<<<<< HEAD
v1.4-alpha-04
=======
v1.4-alpha-03
>>>>>>> v4
```

We resolve the conflict by selecting the `master` content of `version.txt`. We add the file and try to continue our rebase.

```
$ echo v1.4-alpha-04 > version.txt
$ git add version.txt
$ git rebase --continue 
Applying: v4
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To restore the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

It fails ! Let's see what changes `git` think there is in our repository.

```
$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Ah ah, there is no change. If you read in detail the previous error message, `git` informed us of this and recommended to use `git rebase --skip`. He told us "If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch." So we just skip the commit and the rebase succeed.

```
$ git rebase --skip
HEAD is now at 7313eb3 master
```

---

*Word of caution*: Please note that `git rebase --skip` will completely drop the commit that `git` tried to rebase. In our case, this should be okay since `git` is complaining this is an empty commit. If you think you've lost changes once the rebase is complete, you can use `git reflog` to get the commit id of your repository before the rebase, and use `git reset --hard` to get your depot back in that state (this is another destructive operation).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that lengthy explanation Sylvain!  That does make it clearer.  I think i was always just nervous of skipping a patch as it felt like work could get lost: ie that the patch involved all the files affected by the rebase, rather than just the one with the conflict.  Is a patch just a single merge on a single file then?

Comment: No, a patch contains all the difference on all the files modified in a single commit. But when using `git rebase --skip`, you only skip a single commit. I generally issue a `git status` before skipping a commit to see if I am in this situation.

Comment: I just wanted to echo Max in saying thanks for taking the time to write up a great explanation—I finally understand why this is happening. I'm also no longer scared of `rebase --skip` :).

Comment: Warning - if you have several changes in one commit, you may lose work doing git rebase --skip. I just did

Comment: @ChrissyH Unless you did a `git reflog purge` or `git reflog delete` you can still get your changes back by using `git reflog`. Try to checkout the different commit that are referenced there, one of them should be the state of your tree before you started the whole `git rebase`.

Comment: @SylvainDefresne, Btw regarding *"chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes"*, what exactly is that "something else" here? **Is this a Git bug?** (`git rebase --skip` sidesteps the issue, but doesn't solve it.)

Answer (score 23):

Quoting from here: http://wholemeal.co.nz/node/9

> Huh?!? No, I didn't forget to use git
>   add, I did it ... like ... 2 seconds
>   ago!
>
> Turns out that because there is no
>   change from the patch git suspects
>   something has gone wrong. Git expects
>   a patch to have been applied, but the
>   file has remained unchanged.
>
> The error message is not very
>   intuitive, but it does contain the
>   answer. We just need to tell rebase to
>   skip this patch. It's also not
>   necessary to fix the conflict markers
>   in the file. You will end up with the
>   file version from the branch you are
>   rebasing on.

```
$ git rebase --skip
```

Comment: After I used git mergetool and fixed the changes, then added them and committed them, I simply entered <code>git rebase --skip</code> while 'Not currently in any branch.' And everything was fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I think it was a combination of continually running git mergetool, then git rebase --continue, then git mergetool, etc. that finally fixed my situation.

Answer (score 6):

Change app/views/common/version.txt to

```
v1.4-alpha-01
```

At this point in the rebase, remember that you are resolving merge conflicts to show the progression of the *non-master* branch.

So, in rebasing from

```
      A---B---C topic
     /
D---E---F---G master
```

to

```
              A*--B*--C* topic
             /
D---E---F---G master
```

the conflict you are resolving is in how to create A* on the topic branch.

So after doing `git rebase --abort`, the commands should be

```
git checkout topic
git rebase master
< make edits to resolve conflicts >
git add .
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: Thanks unutbu, i tried that but no luck: see OP for new edit.  cheers

Answer (score 6):

That error message is a result of your `git commit -a -m "merged"`. If you just fix up the file, then run `git add <file>`, and `git rebase --continue`, it should work fine. `git rebase --continue` is trying to do a commit, but finding that there are no pending changes to commit (because you committed them already).

Comment: This seems a good deal more reasonable than doing a skip, at least in the general case.  I'm surprised it's not listed as the best answer.

Comment: @EmeraldD., Doesn't work. Fixing the file and running `git add <file>` won't solve the problem. `git rebase --continue` **still** reports *`No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?`*

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you're seeing is not what I would expect from a typical rebase with just this conflict. Consider using a separate branch to do this rebase (especially if you've already pushed the commits remotely that you're fast-forwarding). Also, `git mergetool` can be helpful for resolving conflicts and remembering to issue a `git add`.

In this minimal example, the rebase works as expected. Can you provide an example that shows the behavior you're seeing?

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /tmp
mkdir rebasetest
cd rebasetest
git init
echo 'v1.0' > version.txt
git add version.txt
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git checkout -b v4
echo 'v1.4-alpha-01' > version.txt
git add version.txt
git commit -m 'created v4'
git checkout master
git merge v4
echo 'v1.4-alpha-01-rc1' > version.txt
git add version.txt
git commit -m 'upped version on master to v1.4-alpha-01-rc1'
git checkout v4
echo 'v1.4-alpha-02' > version.txt
git add version.txt
git commit -m 'starting work on alpha-02'

git rebase master
echo 'v1.4-alpha-02' > version.txt
git add version.txt
git rebase --continue
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are some ideas:

- Before starting the rebase, make sure you aren't in the middle of a rebase or am. Do: `rm -rf .git/rebase-apply`

  - if you use Bash, [enhance your bash prompt so it always presents this information automatically](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/164002/focus=164139)
- One bit you mentioned I didn't understand: "and then try to carry on: at first i try a commit:"... why commit? In the middle of a rebase I think you should only "git add" after you tidy up or "git rm" to toss changes or confirm a file deletion. Maybe that messed something up?
- try a [merge instead of a rebase](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.finance.mifos.devel/10872)
- try [some of Ethan Rowe's ideas](http://blog.endpoint.com/2010/08/hopefully-useful-techniques-for-git.html)